# How to change a gherkin text with a variable passed

Tags: cucumber, bdd

I have a Cucumber feature file -

```
scenario : User logs in

Given User launches the site
Then User logs in with UserLogin1
```

Now this `UserLogin1` is actually a variable which i am passing through stepdefinition. So the value for `UserLogin1=automatedUser`. Now when it comes to report currently it prints

```
 Given User launches the site
 Then User logs in with UserLogin1
```

But I want to print as -

```
Given User launches the site
 Then User logs in with automatedUser
```

How can we do that ? Any suggetsions ?

Answer (score 0):

Just write separate scenarios for each user, perhaps using a name to differentiate them.

```
Scenario: Fred logs in
  Given Fred launches the site
  When Fred logs in
  Then Fred should be logged in

Scenario: June logs in
  ...
```

Now because the name of your user is in the scenario your report will tell you who is logged in.